# VSCode Uncss Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: node.js, npm, postcss, parceljs, uncss

I have VSCode, I have installed NodeJS, I have installed NPM.

I was trying to get UNCSS working but cannot seem to get past some errors.

Following this guide here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DX7McYRGJ8o&t=1s

I ran `npm i parcel-bundler -g` Then I had some errors so `npm audit fix` and `npm fund` were ran and it seemed to fix all the errors.

Then `npm init -y` to create a package.json file.

I tried `parcel index.html` and it wont load with out saying

```
Server running at http://localhost:1234
×  
D:\Users\rchow\OneDrive\Desktop\premium-hosting.html\public_html\login\demo: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Users\rchow\OneDrive\Desktop\premium-hosting.html\public_html\login\demo'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Users\rchow\OneDrive\Desktop\premium-hosting.html\public_html\login\demo'
```

I thought maybe I could skip this step,

I ran

`npm i -D postcss-modules postcss-uncss uncss`

created the postcss.config.js file and then tried to run it all but i keep getting the same error as above.

Please help as I cannot work out what is wrong :(

Comment: What is `D:\Users\rchow\OneDrive\Desktop\premium-hosting.html\public_html\login\demo`?

Comment: nothing at all, it doesn't exist which is why I'm more confused than ever.

Comment: Right, which is what the error says. The question is where is your bundler getting the idea to look for that path? Creating a MCVE may help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As RyanZim said -the best thing would be if you could post a reproducible example - maybe on github? But guessing from the error output you're seeing, perhaps there is some kind of link (e.g. `<a href=`) to a file located at `login\demo` within your html or javascript? Parcel works a bit differently from other tools - it will look at the things referenced by `<a>`, `<img>`, etc. from your root `index.html`, and output everything -- and their dependencies -- into the `dist` folder. So you need to make sure that the things referenced within `index.html` (or its dependencies) actually exist.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I will have a good search for the login/demo link, if nothing then I will try and make a reproducible example.